# How to keep tabbing data when editing/replying to a post

Tags: bug, code-formatting

If you edit this question, you will see that the table (below) is formatted, but the result does not look the same.

So how do keep tabbing data?

Table example

Column1     Column2     Column3
texttext    texttext    texttext
texttext    texttext    texttext
texttext    texttext    texttext

Sample image:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about how to show table you know the answer,

```
Table example

Column1 Column2 Column3
texttext texttext texttext
texttext texttext texttext
texttext texttext texttext
```

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>

Cause for coding part everything should be shown in coding markdown.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the preformatted text in `<pre>` tags.

```
Col1    Col2
111     222
```